# Change proxy in angular 4

Tags: angular

I can't change proxy in angular 4.

`proxy.config.json` file:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and `package.json` is:

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully changed proxy today and last week, I was reviewing some applications sent done in Angular 5, and I needed to add proxy to some requests so they would ignore `CORS` issues, anyhow, my assumption is that you are trying out a similar thing, if so, try adding the code below to your `proxy.conf.json` file

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://url.com",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Here is an example how the url is built using proxy:

```
this.http.get('/api/admin/packages');  // https://url.com/api/admin/packages
this.http.get('/api/user/packages');   // https://url.com/api/user/packages
this.http.get('/api2/admin/packages'); // /api2/admin/packages
this.http.get('/user/packages');       // /user/packages
```

Comment: With my code you have successfully changed the proxy, so the proxy is working 100% and the problem is somewhere else, if you wish this to be resolved, open another question or update this one, thanks

Comment: my file is proxy.config.json It is important for run? beacuase do'nt work

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: what is version of angular for you?

Comment: The code above works for every angular version after and including `2.3.1`

Comment: I do'nt know whay do'nt work my code?!!                   I put your code exactly

Comment: Look again at how you implement `HTTP CALLS` and check your `proxy.config.json` again and take a **close look at my answer and at the examples` to figure out what is the issue**